# Image Slider with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I have a requirement of creating an Image slider using Silverlight. I need to display 5 images at first. There will be two buttons previous and next. When I'll click the next button another new 5 images will be shown in place of previously diplayed images. Would it be possible for anyone to tell me the solution for this?

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.
[Image slider control in Silverlight 2](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Image-slider-control-in-Silverlight-1.1.aspx)

Slide.Show 2 - Another cool sample from [Vertigo](http://www.vertigo.com/slideshow.aspx). Source available at [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/SlideShow2).